# Sending an Activity to a non-Android class

Tags: android

I'm pretty much a noob when it comes to Android development. I have an Activity that has a method that pretty much just sets the text of a TextView to whatever text is provided as an argument. I have a second class, which is a Runnable, and I want to be able to give it the Activity (or obtain the Activity somehow), so it can call said method when it needs to.

This Runnable will eventually connect with a server, so it can update the application with information from the server. I've done client/server Java stuff before, so that's not the issue. I just need to figure out how to communicate between this Runnable and the Activity.

Originally, I was going to just pass the Activity itself in, but I read that it would create problems if I did. Instead, I was supposed to pass in an ApplicationContext via getApplicationContext(). I did that, but now I don't know what to do with the ApplicationContext. I tried casting it to the my Activity class, but the program just crashes.

How do I accomplish what I'm aiming at?

Comment: Can you post the code by chance?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you are following Android best practices in your code structure.  Why is a runnable trying to set the text in a text view directly?  Should you perhaps be using an AyncTask for this?  Or a service?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few specific ways in Android to handle threading like `AsyncTask`s etc., you should read up on how to do 'painless' threading [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html). If it's just a one-off task where you connect to the server, get the value, set it in the `TextView` and then finish, I think an `AsyncTask` would be your best option. Continuing background processes are more suited to being [services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your activity to the constructor of your second Class like this :

```
public SecondClass(YourActivity _yourActivity){
this.activity = _yourActivity;
//do stuff
}
```

and in your Activity , you can instanciate your class like this :

```
SecondClass instance = new SecondClass(this);
```

**NOTE :**  in your SecondClass , if you want to change the UI of your application , you can use the method `runOnUiThread(Runnable);`